# Getting bootstrap-slider to fill it's container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3 I'm using the bootstrap-slider from http://www.eyecon.ro/

I've tried all kinds of things including a couple of forks. How do you get this thing to fill its container? It seems to make up some arbitrary widths and puts them in a style tag...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it fill its container you need to add `width: 100%;`to the class `.slider.slider-horizontal` so the code will be like this:

- at **line number 14 in slider.css** file.
- your code must be like this.

  ```
  .slider.slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  }
  ```
- the most important to make this code work don't forget to remove the inline style `style="width: 140px;"` for the **< div** ***class="slider slider-horizontal" >***.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I accidentally had it within an input-group and that was messing everything up.